# Number of continuous real functions satisfying a particular property

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

By just manipulating the given equality the two possible functions are:

$$f(x)= -x \ \ \text{ and  }  \ \ f(x)= x$$

I am not sure if there are other possible functions.

How to figure out all the possible functions?

[image]

Comment: I don't think there are other possible functions

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi But we do need some mathematical reasoning to be sure of it. And by the way it's answer is 4 (option 3) in the answer key given by the university

Comment: $|x|$ and $-|x|$ are also solutions.

Comment: Appreciate the answers but i am looking for a mathematical reasoning or proof which gives exact number of possible functions.

Comment: Hint: See if you can argue that if $f(1)=1$ then by continuity $f(x)=x$ for all $x\geq 0$, similarly if $f(1)=-1$ then $f(x)=-x$ for all $x\geq 0$. Do the same trick with $f(-1)$ and notice that the function is completely determined when $f(1)$ and $f(-1)$ is known.

Comment: You may not state well in your question...it should be x or -x,  not x and -x....

Answer (score 3):

The answer is 4). Consider $\frac {f(x)} x$ on $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$. By continuity the ratio  is a constant $\pm 1$ in each of these intervals and all combinations of signs are possible. [Clearly $f(0)=0$ and you get a continuous function on the whole line for each of these choices of signs].

To be explicit the functions are $x,-x,|x|$ and $-|x|$.

Comment: It should be defined on the whole R...

Comment: @dmtri I am considering continuity of $f$ on the whole line.

Comment: Sorry,  I misunderstood it ) :

Comment: @user684646 The main point of my argument is a continuous function taking only the values $+1$ and $-1$ an an interval has to be a constant. This is a  consequence of IVP.

Comment: Sir what is your reasoning behind considering that new function- f(x)/x at the first place?

Comment: @user684646 It is given that $f(x)=\pm x$ fro all $x$. The question now is whether  the $\pm$ sign can keep changing with $x$ or remains constant. The fact is it can change only when you cross $x=0$ and to prove this you have to use continuity. You can argue without considering the ratio $\frac {f(x)} x$ but the proof is simper if you use continuity of this ratio.